# Can I edit my iOS application's code after getting appID from Paypal for going live?

Tags: ios, paypal

I am about to submit an iOS app to paypal to get a live App ID. However, the code needs some minor changes. So, I want to know if I can edit my app's code after I apply and get a Paypal app ID? Or, do I have to wait until my coding is done and then submit the app to Paypal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app implementation works well in the [PayPal Sandbox](http://developer.paypal.com/), then you are good to go. Most probably PayPal will issue you a Live App ID. All features NEED NOT be entirely functional. Once you obtain your PayPal Live App ID, you can of course make changes to your app, add features to it and fix bugs. Doing so will not void your Live App ID. Keep in mind that any future changes you make to your app will be submitted to the App Store not to PayPal. So technically speaking, PayPal doesn't even know if you made changes to your app or not. The key point here is to make sure your app works well in the PayPal Sandbox -- at all time.

I would also like to clarify one common myth about the Live App ID, for those who are not entirely familiar about what it is. If your App uses the PayPal API, you need a Live App ID before you can test your App on an actual iOS device and/or before you submit it to the App Store. The Live App-ID is provided to you by PayPal, NOT Apple.

To obtain a Live APP ID,

1. Check your account status. Login to [PayPal](http://www.paypal.com/). Go to your PayPal Profile and click My settings. Confirm that your Account type is either Premier or Business, or upgrade your account.
2. Check your API settings. Click My selling tools. Expand Selling online if needed and check API access. Click Update and Add or edit API permission or View API signature.
3. To get your application live, follow the steps outline in [Adaptive Apps 101](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/apps101).
4. Once you've verified that your implementation works correctly in the Sandbox, submit your application to PayPal and you will get your Live App ID.

Comment: One last doubt: do I have to change the paypal recipient's email address to a live Paypal account before submitting the app to paypal? or Can I keep the sandbox account that I used for testing?

Comment: I am not sure. When I did it, I used my real email account. So I know using a live PayPal account will work. But I would guess that they probably run some automated tests that do sanity, positive and negative tests. Hence, I am pretty confident they will use their own parameters to test your app.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "Paypal ID" you mean "Apple ID that PayPal API uses to identifiy your app", in other words, the numeric ID that iTunes Connect gives you when you set up a new app.

The answer is that iTunes Connect gives you this ID as soon as you set up the app on iTunes Connect (i.e. when you put up the description, icon, screenshots, etc). It's not neccesary to actually submit your app binary to get this ID, and you can change the screenshots and description later, so if they're not ready yet, just upload some dummy placeholders for now.

There should be no problem getting your PayPal API set up with your ID before the app is submitted, but you shouldn't upload your app binary if you still want to make changes (although as it happens, you can reject the binary later and upload a new one if you need to anyway, as long as Apple's not already approved it).

Comment: No, in order to use Paypal in an iOS application, we first have to submit the application to paypal's x.com site. Then they will give an applicationID to use in the paypal authentication of the ios application's code. I am asking in regard with submitting the application to Paypal, not AppStore. Currently, I am using SANDBOX environment of Paypal and I want to shift to live Paypal.

Comment: Okay, then you can disregard my answer - sorry.

Comment: The term is confusing and many think the Live App ID is the same as the Apple ID. Live App ID is issued by PayPal once your app is verified to work properly in the PayPal Sandbox.